# gitlab cloud CI: how to increase memory for shared runner

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My Gitlab CI jobs fail because of RAM limitations.

Page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html says:

> All your CI/CD jobs run on n1-standard-1 instances with 3.75GB of RAM, CoreOS and the latest Docker Engine installed.

Below it says:

> The gitlab-shared-runners-manager-X.gitlab.com fleet of runners are dedicated for GitLab projects as well as community forks of them. They use a slightly larger machine type (n1-standard-2) and have a bigger SSD disk size. They don’t run untagged jobs and unlike the general fleet of shared runners, the instances are re-used up to 40 times.

So, how do I enable these `n1-standard-2` runners (which have 7.5 GB RAM)?  I've read the docs over and over but can't seem to find any instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did not check if you can use them with a project and if they picked up for your gitlab CI/CD - but that is the way, of how you can check for available Runners and their tags, and how to use them. The terminology `GitLab projects as well as community forks of them` reads like that this is only for Official GitLab projects and their forks  - and not for random projects on GitLab.

You can check all the available runners in your projects CI/CD Settings under Runners, and you will see a list of runners there like:

[image]

As you can see there are Runners tagged with gitlab-org. Base on the description you can not run them, without using a tag. Hence that you need to adapt your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with those appropriate tags.

EG:

```
job:
  tags:
    - gitlab-org
```

see [GitLab documentation for tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags)